# Read CSV of list of dataframes and convert to list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am currently trying to read a CSV file in that contains a list of dataframes with unequal lengths. At the end of each data frame, there should be `NA` values or a list of letters to separate each data frame. Is it possible to create a new list of dataframes based on this file? I believe this would reduce memory issues for the computer I am running my program on. For example, the below code creates a list of two dataframes. It is separated by their column names.

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2),
                 y2 = c(4, 5))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1),
                 y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
my.list <- list(d1, d2)
lapply(my.list, function(x) write.table(data.frame(x),
                                     '~/mylist.csv',
                                     append = TRUE, sep=','))
```

While I understand that the names don't necessarily correspond to the correct column because of the first column provided. I was still wondering if it was possible to separate out the data into a list of dataframes as I have many more entries than the provided example. If it is possible to remove the first column in the process that would be helpful, but I don't think it is necessary as `[, -1]` seems to work when loading in the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column issue while writing the dataframe can be avoided by setting `row.names = FALSE` in `write.table`.

```
lapply(my.list, function(x) 
       write.table(x,'mylist.csv',append = TRUE, sep=',', row.names = FALSE))
```

To recover the list of dataframes from `mylist.csv` you can do :

```
#read the csv file
dat <- read.csv('mylist.csv')
#Create a group column to split the data
inds1 <- cumsum(dat[[1]] == names(dat)[1])
#Remove the rows where 1st column is equal to first column name.
inds2 <- dat[[1]] != names(dat)[1]
#split the data into list of dataframes
my.list <- split(dat[inds2, ], inds1[inds2])
my.list
#$`0`
#  y1 y2
#1  1  4
#2  2  5

#$`1`
#  y1 y2
#4  3  6
#5  2  5
#6  1  4
```

Comment: When I use the above `row.names = FALSE` I get `Warning messages:
1: In write.table(x, "~/mylist.csv", append = TRUE, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE) :
  appending column names to file` then my result still gives me something different than the above.

Comment: Yes, I get the warning as well but I think it is safe to ignore since it is informing us that column names are being written in the output for every dataframe. However, using the later part of the code works for me as shown in the answer. What does it return for you? Are you testing it on the same data as your post or on different data?

Comment: I was able to get the example code to work. For some reason I get `Warning message:
In dat[[1]] != names(dat) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` and `Warning message:
In dat[[1]] == names(dat) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` with my personal data.

Comment: I changed that to `names(dat)[1]` in both `inds1` and `inds2`.